# What is the probability that the product of two randomly chosen integers has a units digit of $5$?

Tags: probability

> Two numbers are randomly selected and multiplied. Consider the event $E_1$ that the unit's place in their product is $5$. What is the probability of event $E_1$?

**My attempt** : The unit's digit in their product will be $5$ either if both have $5$ in their units place or one of them has $5$ in their units place and the other has a number other than $5$ $($except $0$$)$ in the unit's place. So we have to add the probability of these two cases. The sample space for the unit's digit is {$0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$} so the answer should be $(2 * \frac{1}{10} * \frac{8}{10}) + (\frac{1}{10} * \frac{1}{10})$ which gives $\frac{17}{100}$ but the answer given is $\frac{9}{100}$. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your condition for the product ending in 5 is not true -- you need the one's place of the other factor to be an odd number rather than any number but 5. If we count the possibilities now, one will find that of the 100 combinations of digits in the last place of the two chosen numbers $a, b$ exactly 9 will fulfill this criterion:

1. If $a$ ends in 5 then $b$ can end with any odd digit, giving us 5 possibilities (1, 3, 5, 7 and 9) for $b$'s one's place.
2. If $b$ ends in 5, we also get 5 possibilites just like in the first case, but since we have already counted the case where both $a$ and $b$ end in 5, so we must only count 4 of these possibilities (i.e. $a$ ending with 1, 3, 7 or 9).

So in total we end up with the answer you were given.

Side note: one cannot pick (positive) integers uniformly at random, so I presumed that we pick numbers in the range $[0, 10^k - 1]$ for some $k \geq 0$.